# Problem with two independent Poisson variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

This is the problem.
Two roads A and B lead to a motel. The number of
clients who come to the motel per day on each road are
independent Poisson variables X and Y with parameters r and s
respectively. It is known that the total number of clients who attended
one day it was n.

a) Find the probability that the number of
customers who arrived by road A were k with 0 ≤ k ≤ n

My best approach has been thinking in its their joint probability, and since they are independent it would only be the multiplication of the probabilities.

Then my answer would be $P(X<=k)$ multiplied by $P(Y<=n-k)$ because if $X<=k$ then $Y$ can't be greater than $n-k$ since the total of arrives was $n$, therefore final answer would be:

$$P(X <= k, Y<=n-k)$$

But I fell that is wrong. And my other approach is the sum of $X$ and $Y$, but I don't see much sense doing that.

Someone have any idea?

Sorry if any idea is not understood.

Thanks.